# Is it possible to build a Pattern based on two sub patterns in Java

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(".................");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Since both p1 and p2 are quite long, and it's hard to write a single pattern to cover all cases in p1 and p2. Is it possible to write another pattern p3 that is built upon on p1 and p2, so that I can only run one Matcher:

```
Matcher m = p3.matcher(str);
```

Comment: Do you expecting a string matches `p3` if it matches both or either of `p1` and `p2`? The first is theoretically impossible (for ordinary regex), and the second is already posted in the answers.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Can pattern have some common match? Like `fo` and `foo`? If yes then for data like `foobar` do you want to get as result `fo` or `foo`? If you combine your patterns in a way `fo|foo` then you will never match `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to combine patterns:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".................|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

to match either one:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
```

Comment: I have a lot groups in each pattern, so a simple merge with | would work? What's the scope of the OR operator?

Comment: @user697911 Yes, it works... and the scope is the string you match... to group you can just use `matcher.group()`

Comment: So the scope is the two entire halves (to the very beginning and to the very end) divided by the |, no matter how complex each half is? So the logical OR is greedy. Right?

Comment: I will try. This should work. The only downside is that the new pattern looks too long, a little scary. It would be nice if there is a Pattern p3 = Pattern.combine(p1,p2).

Comment: @user697911, If the answer is useful, you should generally upvote it... (not trying to be greedy, not at all, just the vibe I get from those with `###,###` reputation...

Well, you can combine the strings of the first pattern and the second pattern with `String.join()`

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, match groupings may not work as you expect. Certainly the indexes will be changed (since if you had groups 1,2,3 in the first pattern, and 1,2 in the second, the second groups will now be 4,5). In general you can expect combining with `|` to work for yes/no matching, but not for more complex stuff without some thought.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, just tested and you are right. Then how to extract the groups correctly in this situation?

Comment: Unfortunately, _it depends_. You'd have to post more details about the actual structure of your patterns to get a reasonable answer. It may call for a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can simply combine your *pattern strings* with `|`. If you have the strings representing patterns `string1` and `string2`, then the string `string1|string2` will match *either* pattern. In your example you could use the string `".................|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`.

Of course things become more complicated if you are using capture groups or repeatedly matching the matching the patterns against substrings, since then it's not clear exactly what it means to "combine" the patterns, but for the simple match/no-math case this works.

Comment: *simply combine your patterns*... how?

Comment: Perhaps it is described in the the remainder of the sentence that you cut short? ... and also in the following sentences that make up the rest of the reply? It's almost like you only read the first 7 words and gave up :)

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong at all, I just don't think this is as complete an answer as it could be. How would someone use `|` to combine `p1` and `p2` into a new pattern, `p3`?

Comment: It's already there in the reply: `p1|p2`. To be clear `p1` and `p2` are strings, and `p1|p2` is the concatenation of the characters in `p1`, followed by the `|` character, followed by the characters in `p2`. If `p1` is `cat` and `p2` is `dog`, the result is `cat|dog`.

Comment: In the context of the question, `p1` and `p2` are instances of `Pattern`, rather than strings. So from your last comment I assume there in fact *isn't* a way to create a new `Pattern` by combining two other `Pattern` instances, and rather you're suggesting reusing the regex strings that were used to define `p1` and `p2`. That's the kind of detail that I think would be useful in your answer.

Comment: Heh, good point - I picked `p1` and `p2` arbitrarily not noticing they clashed with the variables in the question. Will change.